# Set up Bundles for TextMate: Location for run command

Tags: textmate, sml, textmatebundles

I have a quick question.
How do I change the "locations searched" for a particular bundle in TextMate?
I installed Standard ML, and I'd like to be able to run it straight from TextMate, but when I try to run it is says that SML is not found. I know where SML is, and it doesn't come up on the locations searched. How can I change this?

Answer (score 0):

If you know where SML is, place an alias of the executable SML program into one of the locations that TextMate is searching, and it should run.